# Where are the images for Cocoa/Cocoa Touch UI elements stored?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, user-interface

I'm looking for the master files for stuff like the OS X traffic lights, or the iOS accessory view symbols. I'm sure I'm just a few search keywords away from the answer, but I haven't been able to figure out what those should even be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OS X, they're stored in the resources of the CoreUI framework. (System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources/)

All the images are compiled into a single proprietarily-formatted binary, that is ArtFile.bin and/or SArtFile.bin. Some people have reverse engineered it. [Here](https://github.com/alexzielenski/artFileTool) is a tool to decode it.

I'd imagine they're stored similarly on iOS, I'm not sure though.

Comment: Thanks. Anyone know where the iOS resources are?